# Creating a basic If Statement for a message box or similar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi people I have the following code (shown below) and I am trying to change it (its my code) so i can display a message box or some alert saying the book has been saved using an if statement in C# ASP.net MVC3

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(BooksItem booksitem)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Booksforsale())
            {
                db.BooksItem.Add(booksitem);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to change this to an If statement so when its saved a message box or an alert appears saying it has been saved. I would like real simple coding nothing to complex that will be hard for me to implement.

Thank You

I have tried the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    If public ActionResult Create(BooksItem booksitem)
    {
        try
        {
            if using (var db = new Booksforsale())
            {
                db.BooksItem.Add(booksitem);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else viewbag.message="been added"
            {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        catch
        {
            return View();

        }
    }
```

This has not worked thank you so much people for any help received really appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the message inside `TempData` so that it is available on the next request after you redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(BooksItem booksitem)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new Booksforsale())
        {
            db.BooksItem.Add(booksitem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        TempData["message"] = "The item has been saved";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and inside the `Index` action that you are redirecting to fetch the message from `TempData` and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = TempData["message"];
    return View();
}
```

and obviously display this message somewhere in the corresponding view:

```
<div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
```